# Accessing certain instance of a Winform control

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, picturebox, visual-c#-express-2010

In this program im writing I use a function to create multiple instances of a PictureBox. This is the code:

```
public void serverCard()
{
    //Definitions
    PictureBox cardBack = new PictureBox();

    //Specifics for card
    cardBack.Size = new Size(cardSizeX, cardSizeY);
    cardBack.BackColor = Color.White;
    cardBack.Left = startX;
    cardBack.Top = startY;

    serverArea.Controls.Add(cardBack);

    //differences in pos
    startX += cardBack.Width + 5;
    if (startX > this.Width - cardSizeX)
    {
      startY += cardBack.Height + 5;
      startX = 5;
    }
}
```

How would I access a specific instance of the PictureBox.
For Example: I create 5 PictureBoxes called "cardBack" using this function. I want to change the position of the second Picture Box that was created, how would I go about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You could either give each `PictureBox` a different name (may be `"cardBack" + ID_in_int`)

```
int picBox_ID = 1;
public void serverCard()
{
    PictureBox cardBack = new PictureBox();
    cardBack.Name = "cardBack" + picBox_ID;
    picBox_ID++;
```

and pull them out of the `Controls` by name:

```
PictureBox temp = serverArea.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name == "cardBack2");
```

2) or you could have a separate collection of type: `List<PictureBox>` where you would store them additionally

```
List<PictureBox> picCollection = new List<PictureBox>();
public void serverCard()
{
    PictureBox cardBack = new PictureBox();
    picCollection.Add(cardBack);
```

and access them in the way you want. May be the order could be of interest.

3) another possibility could be to create a new class that has a property of type `PictureBox` and another property `int ID`. You could have a collection filled with these objects and each object could have a unique ID and the corresponding `PictureBox`. You can still put the picture boxes into the `Controls` and filter the collection according to your needs.

Comment: When using the first method above I got "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"

Comment: @Jumbofile at which line? when you try to access the picbox from `Controls` ? I had a typo in the name string. I changed it. Did you check whether you write the name correctly?

Comment: Yes I changed the name to "cardBack2", This popped up when trying to remove or change visibility of the PictureBox.

Comment: were you able to pull out the right picture box from the `Controls` ?How did you try to remove the picturebox<?

Comment: I tried both `serverArea.Controls.Remove(temp);` and `temp.Visible = false; `

Comment: were you able to pull out the right picture box from the Controls ? or do you get temp as null? in this line: `this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name == "cardBack2");` I am still unclear whether I understand you right

Comment: Found the error, I didnt notice that this line `this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name == "cardBack2");` started with `this.`. The PictureBox is contained in a `Panel` so I had to substitute `this` with the panel name. Thanks.

Comment: @Jumbofile ahh ok, next time you can mention such a nice detail :) I will incorporate this into my answer. Glad to hear that it works

Comment: @Jumbofile It is actually also my fault, since I did not read carefully enough to realize that `serverArea` is the name of the control/panel where you put the picture boxes in. I changed that

Answer (score 1):

Create a method that will return instance of `PictureBox`

```
public PictureBox CreatePictureBox ()
{
  // your code from question here
}
```

then define a field in your form

```
private Dictionary<string, PictureBox> pboxes = new Dictionary<string, PictureBox>();
```

Any time you want to create a new `PictureBox` put it inside `pboxes` collection:

```
pboxes.Add("box1", CreatePictureBox());
```

Now you can access to your boxes like this:

pboxes["box1"].Width += 20;